# App lock not working in android 5.1

Tags: android, devise, applocker

I clone this url to check app lock.
ToolWizAppLock
https://github.com/Toolwiz/ToolWizAppLock

But Its working only for below 19 Api(Android version 4.4.4) and Not working in Above 20 API.

What Should i do to make work on all Android version above 5.0?

Answer (score 0):

activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();

no more available of android version 20 or abouve so you need to change this using below code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) {
                    mPackageName = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
                    mClassName = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).getClass().getName();
                } else {
                    mPackageName = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
                    mClassName = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
                }
```

Comment: where to make this change ?

Comment: when you check for application is run or not at this time

Comment: its working on my application. this is a link of the https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.applockerpro

Comment: i tired your apps on my phone but not working (Android V 5.1.1 API Level 22)